# Calculate the shortest distance between the point $(2, 1, 3)$ and a line with the equation $(3, -4, 3) + t(0,2, 1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I tried finding the vectors magnitude, using dot product and so on but really understanding what approach to take.

I have the point $P = (2, 1, 3)$ in vector form and the line can be seen as a point $(3, -4, 3)$ plus minus a direction depending on $t: (0, 2, 1)$.

So we are searching a vector $v$ from $P$ to some other point on the line $q = a + td$. The searched vector is $v = q-p$. This is where I am stuck, help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The shortest distance is the distance from $P$ to the point $Q$ of the line such that the vector from $P$ to $Q$ is orthogonal to the line, which means that it is orthogonal to $(0,2,1)$. If $Q=(3,-4,3)+t(0,2,1)$, this means that $(1,-5+2t,2+t)$ is orthogonal to $(0,2,1)$. But
\begin{align}
  \langle(1,-5+2t,t),(0,2,1)\rangle=0&\iff-10+4t+t=0\\
  &\iff t=2.
\end{align}
So, the point of the line which is closest to $P$ is $(3,-4,3)+2(0,2,1)=(3,0,5)$. And the distance from $P$ to this point is $\sqrt{6}$.